# How to alert remaining days are finished on date picker?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having trouble to make to alert a popup once the remaining days are finished.
How do I call a function if the remaining days are finished i.e. when the remaining days turn to zero.

```java
try {
     String CurrentDate= curentDate;
     String FinalDatea= FinalDate;
     Date date1;
               
     Date date2;
     SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     date1 = dates.parse(CurrentDate);
     date2 = dates.parse(FinalDatea);
     long difference = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
     long differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
     String dayDifference = Long.toString(differenceDates);
     remainingDays = dayDifference +" days remaining";
     mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ViewWorkEng_page_toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setTitle(remainingDays);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

} catch (Exception exception) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to find date difference", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I've used the above code to get the remaining days between 2 dates. But whenever the CurrentDate and FinalDate become equal it is showing  " 7 days remaining".

Comment: implementing a backgroud service will be suited for your problem. checkout on this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: When do you want this check to happen, once in a day or some other business logic?

Comment: Do you mean that the logic for getting the difference between two dates is not workking?